# Custom block is not showed in header.panel

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento2.4.4, header.panel

Stumbled on this issue:
I need to add a block which switches between Web-pages in a DropDown form.

I am using a custom theme here. Block must be located at this side
[image: Where block must be located]

But the problem is, that when I trying to add a custom block to the container, it's not showing up.

```xml
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
    <block class="<Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Theme\Header\Lang" name="lang_switch" before="header.links" template="<Vendor>_<Module>::language.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

What I tried:

1. Add this to `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Module>/Magento_Theme/layout/defalt.xml`
2. Add this to `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

For knowing what content of blocks:

`app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>/Block/Theme/Header/Lang.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Theme\Header;

class Lang extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function render() {

        $label = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('mysetting/header_lang/hl_label');
        $s_data = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('mysetting/header_lang/hl_data');

        $data = array_map(function($el){
            $d = explode("|",$el);
            return array("order"=>intval($d[0]),"label"=>$d[1],"link"=>$d[2]);
        },explode("\n",$s_data));

        usort($data, fn($a,$b) => $a->order - $b->order );

        $html = '<div class="example-dropdown-2"><span class="action toggle" data-mage-init=\'{"dropdown":{}}\' data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"><span>'.$label.'</span></span><ul class="dropdown">';

        foreach ($data as $d){
            $html .= '<li> <a href="'.$d->link.'">'.$d->label.'</a></li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul></div>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

`app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>/view/frontend/templates/language.phtml`:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @var \<Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Theme\Header\Lang $block
 */
echo $block->render();
```

Data structure of configs:

```
hl_label: text
  example.com

hl_data: textarea
  0|ExampleNET|https://example.net
  1|ExampleORG|https://example.org
  2|ExampleIT|https://example.it
```

Any help with it?
Using:

- Magento: `2.4.4`
- Server: `CentOS`
- Installation: `Bitnami Docker`
- PHP: `8.1.9`
- MySQL: `8.0.30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, i found a solution on my own:
It was a `usort` function.
Why? Idk...